# What's a good C/GDK2 IDE for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ide

What's a good C and GDK+ 2 integrated development environment (IDE) for developing in Ubuntu?

Please state Pros and Cons for each suggestion.

Notes:

- I'm used to using Visual C++ for Windows and C++
- On Linux, I usually use gcc and vi (I'd want something friendlier than GDB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is a fairly solid IDE for writing C/C++, if you use the C Development Toolign (CDT).

Then there's [KDevelop], also quite mature. It was originally meant for KDE development, but you can also use it for plain C if you want to.

Finally, if you want something less integrated, but use separate tools (the Unix way), you should pick a good editor (vim and Emacs come to mind, both have good integration with various tools, such as version control and compiler) plus a debugger. You might also want to look at [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), a frontend for gdb.

As to pros and cons, it really depends on your personal preferences. The integrated version is nice if you like it like it is, but hard to change if you don't.

Also see e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86676/is-there-a-good-and-free-ide-for-c-c-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

The best Linux debugging interface I have seen is gud mode for gdb in emacs (automatically jumps to the appropriate spot in the source code, interactive breakpoints via mouseclick, etc). And speedbar / etags provides a good interface for higher level source browsing in emacs. Sadly vim does not provide process interaction so it can't integrate with a debugger, but definitely learn the tags commands if you are going to stick with vi.

Comment: Debugging *with* `vim` there is always clewn (http://clewn.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, and Pyclewn ,  http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net/